# Poisson Process: Conditional Expectation Word Problem (Computers failing in a lab. Find time of last failure)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Computers in the lab fail, on average, twice a day, according to a Poisson process. Last week, 10 computers failed. Find the expected time of the last failure, and give an approximate time of day when the last failure occurred.

---

I've tried a lot.

My first thought was, "ok, arrival times follow a gamma distribution," so I tried to use that and came up with;

$E(S_{10} | N_7 = 10) = \frac{1}{P(N_7 = 10)} \int_0^7 t f_{S_{10}}(t) dt$

Where $S_{10}$ is the time of the tenth arrival and $N_7 = 10$ states that there were 10 arrivals by time 7 (Sunday in this case).

However, the result is extremely large. Should I be using $P(S_{10}<7)$ instead? The probability I have uses the pmf of the poisson distribution. Which, I'm realizing might not be even remotely proper use of math since it's a continuous distribution's expectation divided by a discrete pmf.

**Edit:** I tried to use $P(S_{10} < 7)$ but it still gets me an incorrect answer. The book claims that the last failure is on Sunday at 8:43 AM. I keep getting Thursday.

Comment: Did you include the "twice a day", so that the rate of the underlying exponential variates is $2$?

Comment: Yes. I have $\lambda = 2$. I didn't write out the full distribution and I realize I didn't write the distributions I used. For this I had $N_7$ being Poisson distributed and $S_{10}$ being Gamma distributed. I tried conditioning on another Gamma but it still gets 4.6279 which is incorrect.